# Android: SugarORM: Listing certain number of records instead of all

Tags: android, database, sugarorm

I am using SugarORM database. I am extracting records by calling

```
String action = "recordId DESC";
db_record_listing = Select.from(Records_rejected.class).orderBy(action).list();
```

However, such database would accumulate over time, and I would like to show the recent 100 records.

### Question:

Is it possible to list out the 100 records that most recently added?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `LIMIT` to restrict the number of items returned.

For SugarORM you can add another chain:

```
Select.from(...).orderBy(...).limit("100").list();
```

Comment: how could I write that out? could you please kindly show explicitly? thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer. What I am not sure of is that parameter String or int.